# select using dynamic list of columns in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have a table `#temp` with certain columns. Each column corresponds to a column name in another table, `#temp2`.

I'd like to do `select colA,colB,colC from #temp2'` where colA,colB,colC are all columns in `#temp`.

The problem is that the col names in `#temp` can change dynamically, and I don't want to hard code the column names into the select query. Is there a way to do this in T-SQL?

Something like,

```
declare @columnList varchar(max);

set @columnList = 
(select (COLUMN_NAME) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where TABLE_NAME = '#temp');

select @columnList from #temp2;
```

Comment: can you add any code you have tried. Please read through [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)

Comment: pseudo code added